# Get key from hash if value in it zero

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have 3 array region ,min,max.If min and corresponding max is both 0 then I want to get the corresponding region into an array.

```
region=["A","B","C","D","E","F","G"]
min= ["0","0","0","200","400","0","0"]
max= ["0","0","0","1000","1000","0","0"]
```

Expected output :

```
output=["A","B","C","F","G"]
```

In the above..ABCFG has corresponding min and max both 0..so I want those region valuse..i.e regions which has both min and max 0

I tried below but no able to proceed furthur

```
Hash[region.zip([min.map(&:to_i),max.map(&:to_i)].transpose)]

//output
{"A"=>[0, 0], "B"=>[0, 0], "C"=>[0, 0], "D"=>[200, 1000], "E"=>[400, 1000], "F"=>[0, 0], "H"=>[0, 0]}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This would do:

```
region.zip(min, max).select {|_, a, b| a == '0' && b == '0'}.map(&:first)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
output = []
region.each_with_index { |r, i| output << r if min[i] == '0' && max[i] == '0' }
output # => ["A","B","C","F","G"]
```

Comment: AFAIK, `x == y == z` will raise syntax error (which is sort of weird, i would rather expect that `1 == 1 == 1` to be false (as `1 == true`) than getting a syntax error)

Comment: Yeah, wrote that before going to bed, sorry

Answer (score 1):

Another way:

```
emin, emax = min.to_enum, max.to_enum

region.select do
  xmin = emin.next == '0'
  xmax = emax.next == '0'
  xmin && xmax
end
  # => ["A", "B", "C", "F", "G"]
```

For extra credit: can this be simplified to:

```
region.select do
  emin.next == '0' && emax.next == '0'
end
```

?